# typescript / javascript array.filter() with multiple conditions not returning expected values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, filter

I have cell definition with two properties:

```
class Cell {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

lets create new array  who contains some cells :

```
let x : Cell[]=[new Cell(5,5),new Cell(5,9), new Cell(5,56)]
```

I would like to filter one cell (if exists in array , and return rest of the array) :

```
x= x.filter(c=>(c.x!==5 && c.y!==5)
```

I`m expecting to get back array with 2  last cells, but it returns none of cells . It works fine if just one condition is used. Any solutions for multiple conditions ?

Comment: None of those cells match your condition, it's unclear why you thought you'd get the last two.

Answer (score 2):

You have the logic wrong. In order to match with `Cell(5,5)` you use

```
c => c.x === 5 && c.y === 5
```

But to filter it out you use the negative:

```
c => !(c.x === 5 && c.y === 5)
```

which is the same as

```
c => c.x !== 5 || c.y !== 5
```

Comment: yeah figured out  there was logic  error. This was what i wanted to achieve. Thnx!

Answer (score -1):

Your Question was a little confusing I'm writing this based on my assumption.

You want to return the last two cells but that condition was contradictory as the last cells are having 5 as the value of x so you can check this condition to return the last two cells.

```
x= x.filter(c=>(c.x == 5 && c.y > 5))
```

In the second condition, I used greater than the operator to get the desired results.

If you found this incorrect let me know I will help.